# Write a program to find remainder of dividing two numbers, without using % operator? In Java

Tags: java

How to find the remainder of dividing two numbers without using the modulo operator!! 
My teacher gave me this exact exercise and It's only my 5th lecture in a course called programming fundamentals.
I have already tried this equation,

```
a%b = a - (a/b)*b
```

but it always returns zero!

Comment: What data type are `a` and `b`?

Comment: You have the right idea, let's see the exact code you wrote to do it, including variable declarations.

Comment: If you've defined `a` and `b` to be doubles or floats, then you'll always get `0` (or a number very close to `0`).  If they're integral types, what you have should work.

Comment: % is not defined for `double`s in Java is it?

Comment: @Quirliom It is. For example you might want to do `1.5 % 1.0`.

Comment: The reason this technique works for integer types is that `a/b` will truncate the result to the whole-number quotient, and then you can subtract to get the remainder. Since you're using floating-point, the truncate doesn't happen automatically, and you'd need to manually truncate `a/b`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just tried this

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    int a = 50;
    int b = 9;

    int c = a%b;
    int d = a - (a/b)*b;

    System.out.println(c);
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

And it seems to work. What types are your variables?

Comment: @user2894634 on doubles it of course will be 0. You can use answer from A Boschman, it will work

Comment: OP said in the question that this doesn't work for him/her.  Repeating the question doesn't constitute answering it.

Comment: Cast the doubles to int's and it should work just fine

Comment: If you cast the `double` values to `int`, then `5 % 1.5` will come out as `0`.  This seems wrong to me.  I think `0.5` would make more sense.

Comment: Guess it depends on what he's doing. If he's using 5.0/2.0 to get remainder 1, this works. With that method, it means you want an integer division result from a division with doubles. OP will need to decide based on what he's doing

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could do what the modulo operator typically does internally.

Inside a loop, substract `b` from `a` repeatedly. When this is no longer possible, the number you're left with is your answer.

Here's a code example.
If you're trying to accomplish this for decimal numbers, be mindful of rounding errors for floating-point values.

```
double result = a;
while(result - b >= 0) {
    result -= b;
}
return result;
```

Note that if you're working with integers, and you're allowed to use the division operator, you don't need to use a loop.

However, do keep in mind that all that division does is repeated subtraction. If this is for pedagogical purposes, I think it's cooler to do it my way.

Comment: thanks that's a good idea! but I haven't studies loops just yet!

Comment: Thanks, fixed it (I hope). Been working for 9 hours, can't see straight anymore.

Comment: I tried this with `a=0.3` and `b=0.1`.  The `result` came out as `0.09999999999999998`.  I think I'll have to keep my downvote in place for now.

Comment: I surrender. My solution is cursed.

Comment: No.  I've just tried `0.3 % 0.1`.  This also gives `0.09999999999999998`, so you have done no worse than the makers of Java.  I think this is an inevitable consequence of the way floating point arithmetic works.  Basically, the `%` operator makes no sense for `double` or `float`.  I removed my downvote.  You could put back your solution the way it was.

Answer (score 2):

It makes no sense to perform `%` on `double` or `float` numbers, because floating point numbers actually each represent a very small range of values, rather than an exact value.  Often, the internal representation of a floating point number isn't the same number in that range as the actual decimal that you used to create the number.  This means that the result of `%` is formally undefined, for floating point types.

If you try `0.3 % 0.1` in Java, you actually get `0.09999999999999998`, which seems at first sight to be incorrect; but this makes as much sense as any other result, given what floating point numbers really represent.

Here is the simplest solution for working out `%`, without actually using `%`.

```
a - b * (long)(a/b);
```

It will perform better than an answer that does repeated subtraction, because it doesn't have to loop over and over.

But this solution inevitably falls victim to the same trap as certain other answers on this page, namely that the "correct" answer is formally undefined.

This solution will also give overflow problems if your numbers are extremely large.

Comment: If `a` and `b` are large, repeated subtraction is unlikely to return the correct result.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg True dat.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the Math.floor of a/b.

you have a%b = a - (a/b)*b
but really a%b= a- (Math.floor(a/b)*b)

This is because without the math.floor it includes the decimal remainder and (a/b)*b is equal to a so when you subtract it from a you will get 0 every time, just as you experienced.

Answer (score 0):

When using `double`s, that equation will always return `0`. When using `int` that equation must work because of truncation (integer division).

Here is the algorithm to compute the remainder in a division. Let's say you want to find `a % b`:

```
while dividend is larger or equal than divisor
    substract divisor from dividend
print last result
```

Implemented in Java it will look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double a = 5, b = 2;

    while (a >= b) {
        a -= b;
    }
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Comment: If you try this with `a=0.3` and `b=0.1`, you won't get the right answer.

Comment: my downvote is locked in, but I want to remove it - see my comment under ABoschman's answer for why.  If you edit this a little, I will undownvote.

Comment: @DavidWallace it has happened to me too. Edited. And thanks for pointing out that issue (with `0.3`, `0.1`). Looks interesting.